# PHP: Can I use account and password to authorize a google-api-client connection?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

In Google Docs api guide, Oauth2 are provided as an authorization method. Here are the authorization code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the console
$client->setClientId('...');
$client->setClientSecret('...');
$client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

$service = new Google_DriveService($client);

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

// Request authorization
print "Please visit:\n$authUrl\n\n";
print "Please enter the auth code:\n";
$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

// Exchange authorization code for access token
$accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
```

However, this kind of authorization requires you to click the link and authorize it manually. What I want is to use email account and password to authorize the connection, is that possible?

BTW, I do not want to use Zend-Gdata. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount).

> For these types of server-to-server interactions you need a service
>   account, which is an account that belongs to your application instead
>   of to an individual end-user. Your application calls Google APIs on
>   behalf of the service account, and user consent is not required. (In
>   non-service-account scenarios, your application calls Google APIs on
>   behalf of end-users, and user consent is sometimes required.)

[Here's a sample code](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/prediction/serviceAccount.php) using the PHP lib.